# Pycharm "Save console output to file" not working

Tags: file, logging, pycharm, console, output

I see that no file is saved even though I specify a file pathname log.log in the logs tab (Run/Debug configurations of Pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the following two boxes should not be checked for this to work:

- Emulate terminal in output console
- Run with Python Console

Uncheck the above two boxes and the logging should work fine. Also remember to specify the log filename instead of directory such as `your_log_directory/log.log`